# Sharepoint List modal popup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list

i have a working sharepoint list that when a user clicked on an item it opened and when the user maximised the modal popup, the content would stretch to fill the size of the modal popup.
Now here is what broke this functionality.
I opened the designer and modified the size of the field text to a larger value (24) for all my field names.

Then i saved the changes - now for some reason when i open  list item the modal popup when maximised does not cause the content to fill the modal popup - it just stays at the default width and does not grow to fill the popup.
I tried reverting the field size to the original but this did not work which is bizarre as it is the only change i made.
How can i fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you change? DispForm.aspx?

Comment: it might be editform.aspx as this is the popup window

Comment: actually its displayifs.aspx

Comment: looking in more detail i think its just the list items when editing that is the issue. They downt fill the screen when opening the modal popup full screen.

Comment: You changed the size of what, exactly, to 24? What was the previous value?

Comment: the font size of an items text. nothing that should break the autofill of the list...